# linear perceptron algorithm

Tags: perceptron

Linear Classification

Consider a labeled training set shown in figure below:

```
Label   -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  +1  +1  +1  +1  +1

Coordinates (0,0)   (2,0)   (3,0)   (0,2)   (2,2)   (5,1)   (5,2)   (2,4)   (4,4)   (5,5)

Perceptron mistakes 1   9   10  5   9   11  0   3   1   1
```

Suppose that we now find the linear separator that maximizes the margin instead of running the perceptron algorithm.

What are the parameters  0  and    corresponding to the maximum margin separator?

Comment: Is it homework? You can solve this using linear regression, I guress: $\hat{y}=(X'X)^{-1} X'y$, or you use logistic regression